# How to disable JavaScript error messages?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, error-handling

I know this seams a trivial question, but how can I disable the annoying JavaScript error messages?

I am inserting data into an unfinished web application and I keep getting about 30 errors for every form I submit. It's driving me crazy.

I'm using IE7.

Please note that I already tried "Internet options - Advanced - Browsing", disabled script debugging for IE and other and unchecked the "display a notification for every script error". All I got was a different error message, but I still have to close a LOT of alert messages.

I think I am going insane.

EDIT: Before and after Image(url omitted to protect the innocents):
[image]

I don't have access to the code, I am just inserting data, the application is still being built and the JavaScript is generated from codebehind. There is absolutely nothing I can do to remove this errors.

Comment: stop making them or correct them? what are the messages of those errors?

Comment: Write error-free code, it’s a win-win situation!

Comment: jQuery is a bad example of this. It has 25 try-catch-blocks. I'd say that it is a lazy programming practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some Googling it seems you might get this if your user-agent string is too long.  See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/scicoria/archive/2009/01/15/adding-web-parts-via-ie-7-and-the-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-complete-this-operation-javascript-error-message.aspx) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/d863c31c-8a50-4e9d-9482-ec479d330658/).  I'm not convinced this will fix it but it might be worth a try.

Comment: The second link did the job :) Thanks :D +1 and accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

If you want to turn them off in code, you can do this:

```
window.onerror = null;
```

Comment: Mmm I've never seen that error before - I'm not 100% convinced it's coming from your javascript, unless you're doing something "interesting" - ActiveX or something...

Comment: @IonutPopa Thanks buddy  you save my day ...   had a minor error in a working code but could't be fixed ..

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't have "enough storage".  Maybe you can try upping your cache size.  That's just a shot in the dark, but worth a try...

Comment: It was a nice try :) I just tried that... with no luck... +1 for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to hide all other errors wrap the call to the code in a try/catch.

```
try {
    callDodgyCode();
}
catch(e) {
    // Eat error
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i did said above: "I don't have access to the code, I am just inserting data, the application is still being built and the javascript is generated from codebehind. There is absolutely nothing I can do to remove this errors."

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you got the correct settings.  Are you sure these aren't alerts actually in the code.

Comment: Yes, pretty sure.... I will add 2 images to the question, before and after the changes in configuration